# Crash due to unaccessable memory in shared memory on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, memory, shared-memory

I created a shared memory using `CreateFileMapping` and get a view using `MapViewOfFile`:

```cpp
  HANDLE hMappedFile =
    CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nullptr, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, DWORD(nSharedMemorySize), L"some-file-identifier")

void* lpViewOfData = MapViewOfFile(m_hMappedFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
```

Then I cast `lpViewOfData` to `unsigned  int *`

```cpp
unsigned int *address= reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(lpViewOfData)
```

when writing to the `address`, the process crashed

```cpp
for(size_t i=0; i<len; ++i){ // len is not out-of-rangle
    address[i] = i;
}
```

I dumped the memory with windbg and get some `??` in the shared memory,which means unmapped address according to [?? in memory locations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3108668/5829527).

```
000001c7`47bc0ff0  00000b18 00000b1a 00000c79 00000b1a
000001c7`47bc1000  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
...// bad
000001c7`47bc1ff0  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
000001c7`47bc2000  00000000 00000000 d3304ef3 10f7808e
...
... // good
...
000001c7`47c2eff0  47c2f000 000001c7 00000000 00000000
000001c7`47c2f000  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
... // bad
000001c7`47c2fff0  ???????? ???????? ???????? ????????
000001c7`47c30000  00000000 00000000 c5305ef5 0101c17e
```

As showed above, these `??` regions are exactly `4k` bytes in length.

I want know what's possible reasons to this problem, does this means hard disk error or wrong operations to these memory(other thread freed these region)?

Comment: Have you done any error checking, that `hMappedFile` and `lpViewOfData` are valid and the functions succeeded? Also, `hMappedFile` or `m_hMappedFile`? Please try to create a proper [mcve] to show us, preferably something which replicates the problem and that we can try out ourselves.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, its OK.Sorry I can't reproduce the problem, it just happened on one of our test machines, so I suspect the hardware error.

Comment: What is the value of `nSharedMemorySize` ?

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis 256MB